# If a graviton is in the atom then why does matter with more atoms still fall at the same rate?

Tags: gravity, matter

If a graviton is in the atom then why does matter with more atoms still fall at the same rate? 
Could it be possible that all atoms are expanding and thus creating an illusion of attraction?

> Earth is expanding which in turn lifts the expanding tree upward and when the expanding apple is released from the tree it no longer has an upward acceleration thus appears to fall as the Earth continues to expand outward?

Comment: *If a graviton is in the atom. . .* Why would you make this assumption? Re the next part: Matter with more atoms falls at the same rate because *each atom* is falling, and the force between each atom and the Earth is approximately the same.

Answer (score 1):

A graviton is a theoretical particle proposed to exist that transmits what we call 'quantum gravity'. But such a form of gravity has not been properly studied yet, and scientists are trying to unify General Relativity with quantum mechanics to study it. It can answer some of the other fundamental questions regarding the universe, once discovered.

So, we don't yet believe that gravitons have an influence on atoms.

The rate at which all objects fall onto the surface of the earth is constant; the speed of every object attracted towards the earth's surface increases by 9.8 m/s^2 every second. This is called acceleration due to gravity (represented by letter 'g') and is part of Newtonian mechanics. This is because 'g' is independent of mass of a falling object. It is only dependent on

1. The attracting body's mass
2. The attracting body's radius, and
3. The universal gravitational constant ('G')

Atoms are not expanding and gravity is not at all an illusion. It is a force that really exists. The universe as a whole expands, but only on large scales. Atoms at such a tiny scale are not influenced by this expansion.